# Powershell script to monitor XML files and run stored procedure if a file is added or updated

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with sub folders that contain XML files.

When an XML file is added, deleted or an existing XML file is updated I need to run a stored procedure in SQL Server and pass the path and filename as a parameter to the stored procedure so it can upload the changes in my database.

I understand (from previous posts) there is a Watcher

```
# Set Folder to Watch 
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Projects"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.XML"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
```

and I've found this PowerShell code to connect to my database

```
# Connect to SQL Server
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=MYPC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MYDB;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = # Call stored procedure and pass my parameter
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close
```

However I'm not sure of rest of the code needed to so that the stored procedure will run once for each new file added, deleted or modified.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what your concerns are?

Comment: I don't know the code to create the action or create the correct events to montior. If I mointor too many events then the stored procedure may run more than once for each file that has been added.